# mysql insert with multiple rows using pdo

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have an associative array containing multiple rows, like as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 37
            [category name] => Cell Phone
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 38
            [category name] => LED Light
        )
```

and so on...

I have the following function to insert the data into my DB using PDO.

```
 function PDOBindArray($poStatement, $paArray){
    foreach ($paArray as $k=>$v){
    $poStatement->bindValue(':'.$k,$v);
} 
  }
```

and here is my insert statement:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO subcategory (cb_category_id,subcategory_name) VALUES (:ID,:category name)");
PDOBindArray($stmt,$data);
$stmt->execute();
```

I get the following error during insert:

Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

I know that this is something silly. But I am unable to locate it...

Comment: `:category name` should be `:category_name` and same in the array.

Comment: can we use quotes ?? i tried it, bit it was not successful. I am getting this array from an external source, converted from a csv file..Is there any other way

Comment: `str_replace(' ', '_', $k)`?

Comment: str_replace(' ', '_', $v)  Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Comment: You have a few other problems as well

Comment: That is the reason i am requesting help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO subcategory (cb_category_id,subcategory_name) VALUES (?,?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
foreach ($paArray as $v){
    $stmt->execute(array_values($v));
}
```